# getting rows that belong to hour range in pandas datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas

Minimal reproducible code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['data'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng)))
df.set_index("date", inplace=True)
```

now I have dataframe like

```
                     data
date    
2018-01-01 00:00:00   47
2018-01-01 01:00:00   97
2018-01-01 02:00:00   98
2018-01-01 03:00:00   36
```

Since I've made its index datetimeindex I can do things like `df["2018-01-01"]` to get only index within January 1st of 2018.

I cannot find any resource that explains way to certain hours.

I want to get hours from 6am ~ 12pm for all days, leading to expected output

```
                     data
date    
2018-01-01 06:00:00   47
2018-01-01 07:00:00   97
2018-01-01 08:00:00   98
.
.
.
2018-01-02 06:00:00   36
2018-01-02 07:00:00   47
2018-01-02 08:00:00   97
.
.
.
2018-01-03 06:00:00   98
2018-01-03 07:00:00   36
2018-01-03 08:00:00   47
.
.
. and so on
```

Comment: is just 6am ~ 12pm?..or also is necesary a filter dates ?

Comment: Is it what you're trying to filter `df.loc[(df.index.hour >= 6) & (df.index.hour <= 12)]` ?

Comment: 6am~12pm for all dates.

Comment: @ATL Yes, but I was wondering if there is more simpler one, taking advantage of datetimeindex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `between_time`:

```
print (df.between_time("06:00","12:00"))

#

                     data
date                     
2018-01-01 06:00:00    51
2018-01-01 07:00:00    61
2018-01-01 08:00:00    37
2018-01-01 09:00:00    77
2018-01-01 10:00:00     7
2018-01-01 11:00:00    59
2018-01-01 12:00:00    69
2018-01-02 06:00:00    85
2018-01-02 07:00:00    70
2018-01-02 08:00:00    72
2018-01-02 09:00:00    55
2018-01-02 10:00:00    27
2018-01-02 11:00:00    32
2018-01-02 12:00:00     8
...
```